# How to convert an object's string value to a dynamic value in .map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of formInputItems with a defaultValue, and when I map throught these I would like to convert the defaultValue to a dynamic value as it recognizes it as a string. So instead of getting back the actual movie title, I get back movie.title as it is in the object. The movie object is passed down as a prop to cardform, how can I make it recognize it? So when I map through formInputItems I want it to recognize defaultValue={`${movie.plot}`} and not defaultValue='movie.plot'

I have an array of objects for the input:

string.js

```
      export const formInputItems = [
            {
                label: 'title',
                defaultValue: 'movie?.title',
            },
            {
                label: 'plot',
                defaultValue: 'movie?.plot',
            },
]
```

the mapping:

```
  const CardForm = ({ movie }: CardFormProps) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const {
        isEditing,
        setIsEditing,
        formData,
        setFormData,
        openForm,
        setOpenForm,
    } = useGlobalContext();


    return (
        <div className='w-full h-full bg-black/80 backdrop-blur-md absolute top-0 left-0 flex items-center justify-center'>
            <form
                onSubmit={submitHandler}
                className='bg-primary p-10 max-w-[450px] w-full flex flex-col gap-4 rounded-md'>
                <TitleTwo>{isEditing ? 'Edit Movie' : 'Add Movie'}</TitleTwo>
                {formInputItems.map(({ label, defaultValue }, index) =>
                    isEditing && (
                        <EditInput
                            key={index}
                            htmlFor={label}
                            id={label}
                            defaultValue={defaultValue}
                            onChange={(e: any) => onChangeHandler(e, label)}>
                            {label}
                        </EditInput>
                    ) 
                )}
    
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CardForm;
```

Comment: Do you control formInputItems? Selecting a variable this way is very difficult, but selecting an object property is simple: you can use variables in bracket notation: if `defaultValue='title'`, then `movie[defaultValue]` is the same as `movie.title`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control with dynamic variables is almost impossible since it needs to be defined first. On the other hand, controlling property of object dynamically is possible.

```
export const formInputItems = [
            {
                label: 'title',
                defaultValue: 'title',
            },
            {
                label: 'plot',
                defaultValue: 'plot',
            },
]
```

```
const CardForm = ({ movie }: CardFormProps) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const {
        isEditing,
        setIsEditing,
        formData,
        setFormData,
        openForm,
        setOpenForm,
    } = useGlobalContext();



    return (
        <div className='w-full h-full bg-black/80 backdrop-blur-md absolute top-0 left-0 flex items-center justify-center'>
            <form
                onSubmit={submitHandler}
                className='bg-primary p-10 max-w-[450px] w-full flex flex-col gap-4 rounded-md'>
                <TitleTwo>{isEditing ? 'Edit Movie' : 'Add Movie'}</TitleTwo>
                {formInputItems.map(({ label, defaultValue }, index) =>
                    isEditing && (
                        <EditInput
                            key={index}
                            htmlFor={label}
                            id={label}
                            defaultValue={movie[defaultValue]}
                            onChange={(e: any) => onChangeHandler(e, label)}>
                            {label}
                        </EditInput>
                    ) 
                )}
    
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CardForm;
```

You might receive type error when using `movie[defaultValue]` so you should define or casting type